# How to setup/configure JBoss?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

Kind of a silly question...

I want to learn J2EE and have been doing some research. I want to build a simple multi-tiered architecture to develop some simple J2EE applications. I plan to use JBOSS as my Application Server and MySQL as my DBMS. I cannot find any simple JBoss installations, they all seem to be bundled in this JBOSS development studio.

Should I use the development studio or is there a better, more 'involved' way to get setup? My concern is that the development studio will not allow me to learn all the bits and pieces of a J2EE architecture.

Thoughts?

Comment: You don't need development studio at all. Grab [**eclipse for JEE**](http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplersr1) as IDE, it is simpler, cleaner and free. Grab [**Apache Tomcat**](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi) as starting app server. Back in eclipse, create some "*Dynamic Web Project*"s and deploy them as `.war` files in the `tomcat\webapp` folder. This will make them run. Check [this link for a **full tutorial** with pictures](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/3/Tomcat-Hello-World-Servlet-using-Eclipse-IDE).

Comment: I've used Tomcat a bit, but want to avoid it since most job postings seem to not want it.

Comment: The only "big" difference between JBoss and Tomcat is that the latter can't run EJBs (aka does not have an EJB container). That's it. You should first learn how to setup web projects that run Servlets and JSP. Tomcat can run them. Then, if ever needed, you can get to learn EJB. When you learn that first part, though, you'll get a much clearer vision of where EJBs fit and how you can go on.

Comment: If you really want JBoss, though, just [**get it**](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads/), and use it instead of Tomcat (replace the appropriate parts on the tutorial). There is no loss. (The only caveat is that some people think JBoss is required to run some simple setups - with Servlets and JSPs only, for instance - and it is not.)

Comment: @acdcjunior is completely right about tomcat for JSPs and Servlets. So if EE "Web Profile" is what you want to do, than Tomcat is OK (BTW the setup for Tomcat in Eclipse is the same as for JBoss. The only difference is, that you do not need additional "Server Adapters". Other option for full EE Server is http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html. Many devs prefer to use Tomcat in combination with Spring Framework instead of EE full profile and Application Server.

Comment: JBoss is called Wildfly now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just my opinion but if you really want to learn how the things works, then use your IDE just for code editing and do the rest from the console, you will see how things works under the hoods.

I am going to describe how to run things under Linux but it's pretty similar to do it on Windows.

For instance, download JBoss from [here](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads), unzip it, go
 in the console to the folder where you have unzipped it and run `sh bin/standalone.sh` - whoa, your server is running now and you didn't need any hardcore setup in your IDE:-)

Then, it's always nice to have some application to get you started. If you are going to build an enterprise application you will definitely need some kind of tool which will manage your dependencies and libraries you will need for your project. In Java world, this tool is most commonly [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/). So install it to your machine (you will find some tutorial for this) and then just issue from command line this command

```
mvn -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=webapp-javaee6 -DarchetypeVersion=1.5 -DarchetypeRepository=http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 -DgroupId=org.yourProject -DartifactId=hello-javaee7 -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackage=org.yourProject.hellojavaee7 -Darchetype.interactive=false --batch-mode archetype:generate
```

Then edit your `pom.xml` which contains dependencies for your project, you see there is just a single one - `javaee-web-api` which will give you everything you need for Java Web development, nice, isn't it?:-)But you have said that you need full Java EE stack, so change this dependency into

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>  
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>  
    <version>7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And you've got even EJB, JTA and other technologies supported in your project. Ok, I now suppose you would like to see your app running, add another plugin to your `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.3.Final</version>
</plugin>
```

And then just issue this command from your project home directory

```
mvn jboss:deploy
```

And that's it, your starter app is available on `http://localhost:8080/hello-javaee7-1.0-SNAPSHOT/`

I guess it's little bit overwhelming for the start but it's not so hard, you don't have to be expert on Maven, JBoss, EJB or any other technology to build enterprise application:-)

P.S. I am not against any IDE but I think it's great to learn these things outside IDE because it will help you understand how things actually works, bonus of this approach is also that you can import this project to any IDE you want and continue development there.

Comment: +1 for understandable, short tutorial. But IMHO just to learn EE, I would prefer to use an IDE with integrated App Server: I can't imagine my work day without hot code replacement (so no need to redeploy every single time).

Comment: Sure but I meant this for a starter, it took me two years to learn that they are things which can be done outside IDE and surprised me that stuff can sometimes be done even more effectively without an IDE:-)

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed explanation! I already downloaded JBOSS and my local server is working. I'm pretty good with Maven already, but didn't know a built in Archetype is already there for a J2EE project, awesome... can't wait to build my first J2EE app, thanks for the nice mini-tutorial!

Comment: One thing to add, the deploy command needs to be mvn jboss:deploy (leave out the -as)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the full Java EE stack, you can still use eclipse (or other Ide) and JBoss locally without the development studio.

Download the latest JBoss version from http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads
(Right now it's AS 7.1.1.Final). It's just a zip file you need to unpack.

In eclipse go to the server view, right click for "New". You need to "Download additional server adapters" and chose JBoss AS Tools from the list.
The rest of the setup is pretty straightforward; Point to the directory with your JBoss AS and you are done.

Make a new project in Eclipse and under "Projects Facets" select "Dynamic Web Module".
Now you can add the project to JBoss (Right click JBoss "Add / Remove".

Start the Server and enjoy your first Java EE Application.

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse tooling is for the more experienced.  I would suggest downloading Netbeans with Glassfish (reference java EE server) as things work out of the box.

Then when you get a bit more experienced you will know what Eclipse needs to function well.

Answer (score 0):

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


                // All three ways will return the same result FYI. You only need to pick one way
                return prov;

            }

            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new Exception("there was a problem");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-Add a menu entry for the contract controller consider the consultant controller
<li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Contract" asp-action="Index">Contract</a></li>
<li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Consultants" asp-action="Index">Consultants</a></li>


    public class WorkSessionMetadata
    {
        public int WorkSessionId { get; set; }
        public int ContractId { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateWorked { get; set; }
        public int ConsultantId { get; set; }
        public double HoursWorked { get; set; }
        public string WorkDescription { get; set; }
        public double HourlyRate { get; set; }
        public double ProvincialTax { get; set; }
        public double TotalChargeBeforeTax { get; set; }

    }
```